# My div is not redirecting using jQuery

Tags: jquery, redirect

Using jQuery from here: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js

```
$(".myBox").click(function(){
    window.location=$(this).attr("http://google.com");
}
```

The above code doesn't work, can someone help me please!

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
```

Answer (score 0):

What TurnItUp posted above should work as well but here you go, the JQuery approach:

```
$(".mybox").click(function(){
    $(location).attr('href','http://www.google.com');
});
```

I also assume that you're wrapping it under "document ready event", correct ?

Full thing should really be

```
$(function()
{
   $(".mybox").click(function(){
       $(location).attr('href','http://www.google.com');
   });
});
```