# My div is not redirecting

Tags: jquery, redirect

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js

```
$(".myBox").click(function(){

window.location=$(this).attr("http://google.com");

return false;
});

div width="200px" height="200px" class="myBox">ggg
div
```

Comment: You're not using .attr() correctly. http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: how many times will you ask this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15281189/my-div-is-not-redirecting-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example

http://jsfiddle.net/axqCK/1/

$(function(){

```
   $(".myBox").click(function(){
       window.location="http://bing.com";
       return false;
   });
```

});

Keep in mind that Some sites like Google will not allow you to load within frames.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there's an attribute in the `div` you're clicking (and I can't think of a valid attribute for a `div` element to contain an `href` value, but regardless):

```
<!-- the following is an invalid use of a `href` attribute, please never do this -->
<div class="myBox" href="http://google.com/">http://google.com/</div>

$(".myBox").click(function(){
    var newURL = $(this).attr('href'),
        newWindow = window.open(newURL, 'newWindowName');
    return false;
});
```

If you're using a custom `data-*` attribute (and you should, if you're doing this):

```
<div class="myBox" data-href="http://google.com/">http://google.com/</div>

$(".myBox").click(function(){
    var newURL = $(this).data('href'),
        newWindow = window.open(newURL, 'newWindowName');
    return false;
});
```

If you're using the *text* of the `div`:

```
<div class="myBox">http://google.com/</div>

$(".myBox").click(function(){
    var newURL = $(this).text().trim(),
        newWindow = window.open(newURL, 'newWindowName');
    return false;
});
```

The reason your code wasn't working was this line:

```
window.location = $(this).attr("http://google.com");
```

`attr()` is a getter, or setter; to *get* the value of an attribute:

```
window.location = $(this).attr('nameOfAttribute');
```

To *set* an attribute's value:

```
window.location = $(this).attr('nameOfAttribute', 'valueOfAttribute');
```

You, in your code, were trying to *retrieve* the value of the `http://google.com` attribute; which, needless to say, did not exist.

references:

- [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).
- [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).
- [`trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/trim/).

Comment: I set this up here and it's still not working....see source code in browser.... http://supersimplescripts.com/dom/test.htm

Comment: got it to work my mistake but can we have it open in same window as well

Comment: It should already open in the same window; that's what `window.location` *does*.

Comment: sorry open in new window please

Comment: Updated the code to show how to open the URL in a new window.